# Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) when implementing pagination

Tags: php

i am trying to implement a form of pagination system using PHP and MYSQL by following a tutorial that I found online. I am having some issues with the actual code that I got. I am receiving the error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

This is the PHP code that is relevant for the problem:

```php
require_once 'dbh.inc.php'; 

$perpage = 5;
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'portfolio'");
$stmt->execute();
$entries = $stmt->fetchColumn();
$totalPages = ceil($entries / $perpage);

$pageNow = isset($_GET["page"] ? $_GET["page"] : 1);

$x = ($pageNow  - 1) * $perpage;
$y = $perpage;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'portfolio' ORDER BY 'work_id' LIMIT $x, $y";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$posts = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

The line that gives me the error is:

```php
$pageNow = isset($_GET["page"] ? $_GET["page"] : 1);
```

I cant seem to find a solution for it. Sorry if the question is poorly written or described.

Comment: `isset()` is a language construct to determine if a variable exists, it doesn't make sense to apply it to an arbitrary expression. For what it's worth, you can just do `$pageNow = $_GET["page"] ?? 1;`.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$pageNow = isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : 1;
```

- Condition : is GET["page"] set ?
- If yes : use it.
- If not : use 1.

Comment: The explanation is a nice addtion in this answer, perhaps you should refer to the [Ternary Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) you use. Your code is the same as: `$pageNow = $_GET["page"] ?? 1;` See: [Null Coalescing Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware ah nice, didn't know that one. Then I haven't used PHP since version 5.